# how to use switch statements with integer expression?

Tags: r, switch-statement, conditional-statements, rstudio

```
The below results in an error:
a = 3
switch(a,
       1 = {print(1)},
       2 = {print(2)},
       3 = {print(3)},
       {print("null")}
       )


> source('~/.active-rstudio-document', echo=TRUE)
Error in source("~/.active-rstudio-document", echo = TRUE) : 
  ~/.active-rstudio-document:3:10: unexpected '='
2: switch(a,
3:        1 =
            ^
```

Why integer values cannot be used in the above case? Does switch only work with characters ?

Comment: It is not that you cannot use integers. You have the wrong syntax for the switch statement.  Please type `?switch` and read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax for numeric switch:

```
switch(a,
   print(1),
   print(2),
   print(3),
)
```

If `a not in c(1:3)`, this returns `NULL`.